# Loop through num_machines In the below script the value in expression num_machines=X the value will change every time

Tags: linux, shell, sh, ksh

For the below script if the MACHINES_NUM changes suppose if the MACHINES_NUM is 3 or 4. Then my Script should use the value in MACHINES_NUM.

MACHINES_NUM=x

then it should use 4 if its 3 then it should use 3. The MACHINES_NUM value will always change every time we run the script.

```
if [ "$MACHINES_NUM" = x]
```

then

mkdir -p /RDS_RO/HOME/MACHINE1

mkdir -p /RDS_RO/HOME/MACHINE2

fi

something like

for LOCATORS_NUM in 1 2 3 4 5

do

echo "Welcome $LOCATORS_NUM times"

done

Someone please help......

Comment: Why do you have to use `ksh`? And, why have you tagged it as as `bash` which is not `ksh`?

Comment: because all the scripts on my server are ksh 
@MarkSetchell

Comment: Do you ask how to make `if/else` in shell ?

Comment: yes your right @Zulu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In POSIX shell, compatible with `ksh` and other shells:

```
if [ "$MACHINES_NUM" = 2 ] 
then
    mkdir -p /RDS_RO/HOME/MACHINE1
    mkdir -p /RDS_RO/HOME/MACHINE2
fi
```

Comment: The space was missing from the original, and I failed to insert it the first time around.

Comment: The MACHINES_NUM value will always change every time we run the script. suppose the first when we run it it may get 2 and then it may get a value of 5. So how should I give the value of MACHINES_NUM. @chepner